# CMake custom clean commands

Tags: command, cmake

In my CMake project I'd like to have some custom behavior happen when the clean target is run.  However, if I do

```
add_dependencies(clean extra-clean)
```

it fails with

```
add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target: clean
```

Is it even possible to have custom clean behavior?

**EDIT:** I am running some external tools as part of the build.  These tools generate lots of files, but they can be cleaned up simply by asking the tool to do so.  Ideally, I could add a custom target to the clean target to call the tool to do its cleanup.

Comment: I'd still like to know the answer to the clarified question! None of the current answers actually answer it. How to run some extra commands when "make clean" is run, e.g. the "make clean" of an external tool?

Comment: Same issue I want to add a custom "action" to the global clean target.  or a custom command or a custom target clean is dependent upon so it will get called when "clean" is requested.

Comment: Same here... there are still no answers that explain how to execute a custom command whenever the `clean` target is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the custom behavior you are looking for? If you need to remove files you can use 
[set_directory_properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aset_directory_properties).

Comment: Fortunately, the external tool I'm using can be configured to put everything in one directory, which allows me to use set_directory_properties. :)

Comment: I'm working with a tool that can not really be configured in such a way. Is there any way we can tell CMake to remove files matching a specific name (with a wildcard)?

Comment: It is not clear to me which property to set that will allow for the desired behavior.

Comment: Bear in mind it only works in Makefile generators (as the name suggests)

Comment: Please give a complete example of how to add a directory to the clean target.

Comment: Here is an example:   
`set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES path_of_directory_to_clean)`
I am using this to clean up the directories generated by a custom Makefile-based target (add_custom_target).

Comment: That's not good enough. For example, when the user needs to run a custom command to clean up leftover Conan packages.